# Rspec and rails mailers throws nil for nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, actionmailer

I'm trying to test a Mailer but I can't figure why I'm not reaching a nested model attribute in mailer

let's see, I have this models

```
class CandidateChallenge < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :candidate_evaluation
  def coach
    self.candidate_evaluation.user
  end
end

class CandidateEvaluation < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :candidate_challenge
end
```

In mailer I have

```
def notify_coach(candidate_challenge_id)
  @candidate_challenge = CandidateChallenge.find(candidate_challenge_id)
  @user = @candidate_challenge.user
  @coach = @candidate_challenge.coach # <= throws nil
  mail(
    to: @coach.email, # <= this is nil too
    cc: @user.email,
  )
end
```

And in my test I have

```
let!(:user) { create(:coach_user) }
let!(:candidate_challenge) { 
    create(:candidate_challenge, user: user) 
}
let(:job) { NotificationMailer.new }

# Test passing
it "should have a coach" do
    expect(candidate_challenge.coach.email).to eq(candidate_challenge.candidate_evaluation.user.email)
end

# Test failing
it "job is created" do
  ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :test
  expect {
    job.notify_coach(candidate_challenge.id).deliver_now
  }.to change { 
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs.size 
  }.by_at_least(1)
end
```

#### Error

```
Failure/Error: to: @coach.email,

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

#### With pry

asking from model throws nil

```
CandidateChallenge.last.candidate_evaluation 
=> #<CandidateEvaluation:0x0000000111b25ab8
 id: 25,
 candidate_challenge_id: 13,
 user_id: nil>

CandidateChallenge.find(candidate_challenge.id).candidate_evaluation
=> #<CandidateEvaluation:0x000000012223a668
 id: 25,
 candidate_challenge_id: 13,
 user_id: nil>
```

from factorybot gives expected result

```
candidate_challenge.coach.email
=> "test26@example.com"

candidate_challenge.candidate_evaluation.user
=> #<User id: 26, email: "test26@example.com" ...>

candidate_challenge.candidate_evaluation
=> #<CandidateEvaluation:0x00000001218357f8
 id: 26,
 candidate_challenge_id: 13,
 user_id: 26>
```

So, I'm wondering why if I ask in mailer from class model `CandidateChallenge.find(candidate_challenge_id)` user_id is nil?, how can I test `notify_coach` method with rspec without losing this relationship?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that `let!(:user) { create(:user) }` is a coach user

Comment: let!(:candidate_challenge) { 
    create(:candidate_challenge, user: user) 
}
Why user: user
I think it should be `coach: user`.

Comment: @HirenBhalani oh, user is a coach factory, coach method (from CandidateChallenge class) calls a relation to candidate_evaluation, like candidate_challenge.candidate_evaluation.user is the same that candidate_challenge.coach, I forgot to mention that create(:user) is the same that create(:coach_user) sorry

Comment: What you have provided is incredibly confusing and not enough to diagnose the problem. `CandidateChallenge` has no `user` method but you are calling it apparently without error in your mailer. You also say if you create challenges in FactoryBot they work fine, but you've not provided the code you used to create them, and you've given no factory code. I'd double check `@user.email` is not the problem. You're also changing the queue adapter yet calling `deliver_now` which doesn't make sense, although that's perhaps tangential.